# I want to make tab related to date the content changes as the date changes

Tags: javascript

I want to insert three tabs in my app **yesterday** **Today** and **tomorrow**
And add nearly 50 png images. I want to relate those tabs with these images. I am using viewpager with slide view.
The middle **today** tab is default tab And as the date changes want to show next image as default. In this way want to show all 50 images in 50 days ...
please suggest code in mainactivity.java

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: New at Java ... Please explain from beginning...